# boot to black screen after upgrade

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, nvidia, upgrade

I upgarted from 14.04 to 16.04.
after boot the terminal `tty1` opens, and a message is repeated:

```
brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated 
brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
```

I have a dual boot system (windows bootloader is still working),
I also have nvidia geforce.

`ifconfig` shows both `wlan0` and `eth0` are up but without `ip`.

**can you identify the problem? how can I fix it?**

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The information you showed was just the dmesg of the wireless configuring itself.

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

Apart from this, it seems your system is fine (from what you've described) besides booting to tty1 instead of tty7.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I wasn't clear, tty7 is just black screen, that's the problem.

dmesg with AGP search result:

```
[    0.000000] AGP: No AGP bridge found
[    0.000000] AGP: Checking aperture...
[    0.000000] AGP: No AGP bridge found
[    0.740045] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    0.740141] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: Intel HD Graphics Chipset
[    0.740160] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected gtt size: 2097152K total, 262144K mappable
[    0.740724] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected 65536K stolen memory
[    0.740963] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: AGP aperture is 256M @ 0xd0000000
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce 310M] (rev a2)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

If there anything else relevant I can add please tell.

Thank you in advance for your help.